# PHP array - appending number (value) to string (key) for each element

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, sequence, shuffle

I have an array like

```
$a = array
     (   
        "Leafs",  
        "Sabres",  
        "Red Wings",  
        "Flyers"
     );
```

that I shuffle `shuffle($a);`

The resultant array could be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sabres
    [1] => Red Wings
    [2] => Leafs
    [3] => Flyers
)
```

With the resultant array, I now want to append a sequential number twice starting with `1` to each element in the array such that `$a` becomes:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Sabres
    [1] => Red Wings
    [2] => Leafs
    [2] => Flyers
)
```

The number ends with `2` in this array, but should continue until there are no more elements to number in the array. How can this be done programmatically?

Comment: You can't have array with not unique keys. So `[1] => Sabres
    [1] => Red Wings` is wrong. What is your the real problem?

Comment: Array index must be unique. You can do a multi-dimentional array rather
`array (
1 => array(
 'Sabres',
 'Red Wings',
 ),
 2 => array(
  'Leafs',,
  'Flyers'
 )
)`

Comment: @TeddyPatriarca Maybe, OP only wants to use array_chunk. Or, maybe, some else.

Comment: @splash58 can I set `Sabres` as the key and `1` as the value?

Comment: If values are unique, you can

Comment: What is your end purpose? Do you want to get pairs?

Comment: @freeek I want to pair each element with another element randomly, the number assignment is to designate the pairs

Comment: `array_chunk($array,2)`

Comment: Then use @splash58 solution :)